# How to set a breakpoint on a website's javascript (i.e. not yours) in Chrome dev tools?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I want to know the values of some javascript variables running on a website.
How can I inspect this, if the website is not mine?

For example, this is [topbar.js](http://sstatic.net/stackexchange//js/topbar.js) from [StackExchange toppage](https://stackexchange.com/):

```
! function(t, e, n) {
    "function" == typeof define ? define(n) : "undefined" != typeof module ? module.exports = n() : e[t] = n(e)
}("klass", this, function(t) {
    function e(t) {
        return o.call(n(t) ? t : function() {}, t, 1)
    }

    function n(t) {
        return typeof t === r
    }

    function i(t, e, n) {
    //script continues...
```

How do I set a breakpoint or know the value of `t` when it's called, for example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open dev tools on the website by pressing Ctrl+Shift+i.

Go to the Sources tab.

Open the desired js file with Ctrl+P.

This particular file is minified. You can unminify it by pressing the `{}` button at the bottom left of the code window.

Now you can add a breakpoint just like in your own page.

Comment: Thanks, also for Ctrl+P. I'm sort of ashamed of myself for not knowing this.

Answer (score 1):

Clicking on the line number on the left of the Sources tab from Chrome dev-tools adds a breakpoint